# Class for easy generation of xpaths

Tags: java, selenium

I would like to write a class for generating xpaths. The class should have 2 methods: `down(String string)` and `child(String string)`.

I would like to use the class like that:

```
XpathBuilder.child("div").down("button").child("a").child("span")

//That should return a String: div//button/a/span
```

Could anybody suggest me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at builder pattern.

Here is one example (uses internal builder class):

```
public class XpathBuilder {

    public Builder builder() {
        return new XpathBuilder.Builder();
    }

    class Builder {

        private final StringBuilder sb;

        Builder() {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        }

        public Builder child(String name) {
            sb.append("/").append(name);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder down(String name) {
            sb.append("//").append(name);
            return this;
        }

        public String build() {
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

It can be called like this:

```
String path = new XpathBuilder().builder().child("div").down("button").child("a").child("span").build();
```

Here is another example (uses builder as well as singleton pattern):

```
public class XpathBuilder {

    private final StringBuilder sb;

    private static XpathBuilder instance;

    private XpathBuilder() {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public static XpathBuilder newInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new XpathBuilder();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public XpathBuilder child(String name) {
        sb.append("/").append(name);
        return this;
    }

    public XpathBuilder down(String name) {
        sb.append("//").append(name);
        return this;
    }

    public String build() {
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

It can be called like this:

```
String path = XpathBuilder.newInstance().child("div").down("button").child("a").child("span").build();
```

Comment: is it possible somehow to do it without adding builder() or build() everytime?

Comment: You should let this builder know somehow, that it should start accumulating new data and that data accumulation is finished and it should return the resulting XPath. This is achieved by calling builder() (which initializes new StringBuilder) and build() (which returns resulting string from StringBuilder). Although it would be possible to get rid of the builder() call, it would require to make child() and down() methods more complex by adding checks whether StringBuilder is already initialized or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an easier solution overriding the toString method from the class Object. Doing that I need only one class:

```
public class XpathBuilder {

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public XpathBuilder child(String string) {
    sb.append("/"+string);
    return this;
}

public XpathBuilder down(String string){
    sb.append("//"+string);
    return this;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return sb.toString();
}
```